# Remove by _id inside a nested array, inside of a collection

Tags: mongodb, express

this is my mongoDb footballers collection :

```
[
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d83b4a7e5511f28847f1884"),
        "prenom" : "djalil",
        "pseudo" : "dja1000",
        "email" : "djalil@gmail.com",
        "selectionned" : [ 
            {
                "_id" : "5d83af3be5511f28847f187f",
                "role" : "footballeur",
                "prenom" : "Gilbert",
                "pseudo" : "Gilbert",
            }, 
            {
                "_id" : "5d83b3d5e5511f28847f1883",
                "role" : "footballeur",
                "prenom" : "Xavier",
                "pseudo" : "xav4544",
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5d83afa8e5511f28847f1880"),
        "prenom" : "Rolande",
        "pseudo" : "Rolande4000",
        "email" : "rolande@gmail.com",
        "selectionned" : [ 

            {
                "_id" : "5d83b3d5e5511f28847f1883",
                "role" : "footballeur",
                "prenom" : "Xavier",
                "pseudo" : "xav4544",
            }
        ]

    }

}
```

How could I delete each selectionned people who has the 5d83b3d5e5511f28847f1883 _id through all of the collection?

I do need xavier to deseappear from any 'selectionned' array , just like doing a 'delete cascade' in SQL language

This is what I've tried with no luck :

```
   function delete_fb_from_all(fb){
        var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID; //working
        var idObj = ObjectId(fb._id); //working

    try {
            db.collection('footballers').remove( { "selectionned._id" : idObj } );
            console.log('All have been erased');    

        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
    }

}
```

And this too is not working :

```
db.collection('footballers.selectionned').remove( { "_id" : idObj } );
```

i really dont know how to do this.

i'm trying out this right now :

```
db.collection.update({'footballers.selectionned':  idObj }, {$pull: {footballers:{ selectionned:  idObj}}})
```

This is the error :

```
TypeError: db.collection.update is not a function
```

I think that the solution is maybe there : 
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/pull/#pull-array-of-documents

**EDIT 1**

i'm currently trying ou this :

```
var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID; //working
        var idObj = ObjectId(fb._id); //working
        try {
            db.collection('footballers').update(
              { },
              { $pull: { selectionned: { _id: idObj } } },
              { multi: true }
            )
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);

        }
```

**SOLVED :**

Specifiying the email, it is now working, I guess the problem was comin from the _id field :

```
try {
    db.collection('footballers').update(
      { },
      { $pull: { selectionned: { email: fb.email } } },
      { multi: true }
    )
} catch (e) {
    console.log(e);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Object ID :

The issue is may be on your object id creation. No need to make string-id with mongoDB object id.

```js
    // No need
    var ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectID;
    var idObj = ObjectId(fb._id);

    // do as normal string
    db.collection('footballers').remove( { "selectionned._id" : fb._id } );
```